# Can't call a method, trying to get a variable from one method to another

Tags: java, methods

I am stuck trying to call a method. No matter what I do, I get an error that it can't find the symbol. I am trying to use the variables total (from the surfaceArea method) and volume (from the volume method).

The problems are in the toString method, where it cannot see the variables no matter what I do. I am sure it is something incredibly basic I a missing, so I hope someone can figure it out.

Here is the Error Log:

```
Ellipsoid.java:176: error: cannot find symbol
     String vout = df.format(volume);
                             ^
 symbol:   variable volume
 location: class Ellipsoid
Ellipsoid.java:177: error: cannot find symbol
     String sout = df.format(total);
                             ^
 symbol:   variable total
 location: class Ellipsoid
2 errors
```

And here is the code itself. I tried to make it as easy to read as possible:

```
/**
* This program lets the user enter values of and Ellipsoid. 
* @version 02/05/2020
*/
public class Ellipsoid {

// fields

   private String label;
   private double a, b, c;
   //public double total, volume;
// constructor
/**
* This constructor creates a ellipsoid and gets its information.
*
* @param labelIn is the label entered by the user.
* @param aIn is the a valuve entered by the user.
* @param bIn is the b valuve entered by the user.
* @param cIn is the c valuve entered by the user.
*/
   public Ellipsoid(String labelIn, double aIn, double bIn, double cIn) {
      setLabel(labelIn);
      setA(aIn);
      setB(bIn);
      setC(cIn);
   }
// methods
/**
* This method gets the label string.
* @return returns the label of the ellipsoid.
*/
   public String getLabel() {
      return label;
   }
     /**
* This method sets the label of the ellipsoid.
* @param labelIn is the label entered by the user.
* @return returns true or false depending on user input.
*/
   public boolean setLabel(String labelIn) {
      if (labelIn == null) {
         return false;
      }
      else {
         label = labelIn.trim();
         return true;
      }
   }
     /**
* This method gets the a values of the ellipsoid.
* @return returns a values of the ellipsoid.
*/
   public double getA() {
      return a;
   }
     /**
* This method sets the a value of the ellipsoid.
* @param aIn is the a value entered by the user.
* @return returns true or false depending on the user input.
*/
   public boolean setA(double aIn)
   {
      if (aIn > 0)
      {
         a = aIn;
         return true;
      }
      else 
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
     /**
* This method gets the b value of the ellipsoid.
* @return returns the b value of the ellipsoid.
*/
   public double getB()
   {
      return b;
   }
     /**
* This method sets the b value of the ellipsoid.
* @param bIn is the b value entered by the user.
* @return returns true or false depending on the user input.
*/
   public boolean setB(double bIn)
   {
      if (bIn > 0)
      {
         b = bIn;
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
   }

 /**
* This method gets the c value of the ellipsoid.
* @return returns the c value of the ellipsoid.
*/

   public double getC()
   {
      return c;
   }
     /**
* This method sets the c value of the ellipsoid.
* @param cIn is the c value entered by the user.
* @return returns true or false depending on the user input.
*/
   public boolean setC(double cIn)
   {
      if (cIn > 0)
      {
         c = cIn;
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
   }

     /**
* This method finds the volume of the ellipsoid.
* @return returns the volume of the ellipsoid.

*/
   public double volume()
   {
      double volume = 4 * Math.PI * a * b * c;
      volume = volume / 3;
      return volume;
   }

/**
* This method finds the surface area of the ellipsoid.
* @return returns the surface area.
*/
   public double surfaceArea() {

      double ab = (a * b);
      ab = Math.pow(ab, 1.6);
      double ac = a * c;
      ac = Math.pow(ac, 1.6);
      double bc = b * c;
      bc = Math.pow(bc, 1.6);

      double top = ab + ac + bc;
      double bottom = top / 3;
      double full = bottom * 1 / 1.6;
      double total = 4 * Math.PI * full;
      return total;  

   }



     /**
* This method prints the information of the ellipsoid.
* @return returns the information of the ellipsoid.
*/
   public String toString() {
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0###");
      surfaceArea();
      volume();

      String aout = df.format(a);
      String bout = df.format(b);
      String cout = df.format(c);
      String vout = df.format(volume);
      String sout = df.format(total);


      String output = "Ellipsoid \"" + label + "\" with axes a = " + aout
         + ", b = " + bout + ", c = " + cout + " units has:\n\tvolume = " 
         + vout + " cubic units\n\tsurface area = "
         + sout + " square units";
      return output;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`volume` and `total` are local members to `volume()` and `surfaceArea()` methods respectively. It is not visible in `toString()` method. But a, b and c are visible as they are declared class level. Try assigning returned values from those methods to local variables in `toString()` as below:

```
public String toString() {
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0###");
  double total = surfaceArea();
  double volume = volume();

  ....
  String vout = df.format(volume);
  String sout = df.format(total);
  ....
}
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In the Ellipsoid class, you didn't declare the `total` and `volume` variables.
They are commented there, try to uncomment this line:

```
//public double total, volume;
```

Should help, but if you want to assign the values to those instance fields while calculating, change the `double total` and `double total` in the proper methods to `this.total` and `this.volume`.
This will allow you to both keep the data inside object and return it through method.

Comment: Thanks, I knew It something I was mssing.